# solitaire game. How to all strings will transfer to an designated array and upper strings will turn to asterisk

Tags: java

It is like a solitaire game. How to the All strings will transfer to an designated array and How to all upper strings will turn to an asterisk stands for a back of card in solitaire.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
//Strings that stands for cards.
String[] shuffled;
 shuffled= new String[52];
String[] cards =
    { "A@", "A#", "A$", "A&", "2@", "3@", "4@", "5@", "6@", "7@", "8@", "9@",
        "10@", "K@", "Q@", "J@", "2#", "3#", "4#", "5#", "6#", "7#", "8#",
        "9#", "10#", "K#", "J#", "2$", "3$", "4$", "5$", "6$", "7$", "8$",
        "9$", "10$", "K$", "Q$", "J$", "2&", "3&", "4&", "5&", "6&", "7&",
        "8&", "9&", "10&", "K&", "Q&", "J&", "Q#" };

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(cards);
//Shuffle.
Collections.shuffle(list);
final int columns = 7;
final int rows = 7;
int card = 0;

// loop over rows.In this stage i want to transfer all the codes in an array.
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    // Fill empty columns in this row
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    // Add #columns - row# cards to this row

    for (int j=i; j<columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(card++) + "\t");
    }
    // advance to next row
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: You've not asked us a question. Can you explain what is wrong with this code, what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: I'm creating a solitaire game, that user can play in console without GUI. How to place the string in the designated array after shuffling and looping it ? And  how to all the Upper String will turn to asterisk stands for a back card in solitaire ?

Comment: Place which string into which array? I don't understand your second sentence at all: "*And how to all the Upper String will turn to asterisk stands for a back card in solitaire*" - can you reword that?

Comment: Into Shuffled Array that I declared. After looping and shuffling the elements will go into the shuffled array. In the solitaire game the asterisk will stands for facing down card.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Instead of storing the cards as Strings and then somehow keeping track of whether they are face up or down, consider encapsulating the value and suit of a card in a class, along with information about whether it is exposed.

```
public class Card {
    String value;
    String suit;
    boolean exposed;

    public Card(String id) {
        int size = id.length();
        this.value = id.substring(0, size-1);
        this.suit =  id.substring(size-1, size);
    }
    public Card show() {
        exposed = true;
        return this;
    }
    public Card hide() {
        exposed = false;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(exposed) {
            return(value + suit);
        } else {
            return "*";
        }
    }
}
```

Cards are constructed, face down by default, by calls such as

```
Card c = new Card("A#");
```

so you can construct your cards by passing the elements of your card array to the constructor.

Calls to `show` and `hide` change whether the card is exposed or not, and the `toString` method means that you can just print out each card and the calling code does not need to know whether the card is face up or down - it is the `Card` class which determines whether the value or `*` is printed.

Then define a Pack which consists of 52 cards to implement shuffling and dealing:

```
public class Pack {
    List<Card> pack = new ArrayList();
    Iterator<Card> iterator;

    public Pack() {
        String[] cards =
        { "A@", "A#", "A$", "A&", "2@", "3@", "4@", "5@", "6@", "7@", "8@", "9@",
        "10@", "K@", "Q@", "J@", "2#", "3#", "4#", "5#", "6#", "7#", "8#",
        "9#", "10#", "K#", "J#", "2$", "3$", "4$", "5$", "6$", "7$", "8$",
        "9$", "10$", "K$", "Q$", "J$", "2&", "3&", "4&", "5&", "6&", "7&",
        "8&", "9&", "10&", "K&", "Q&", "J&", "Q#" };
        for(String card : cards) {
            pack.add(new Card(card));
        }
    }
    void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(pack);
    }

    void startDealing() {
        iterator = pack.iterator();
    }

    public Card nextCard() {
        return(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Note how the pack is manipulated by a simple constructor, a `shuffle` method and dealing with `startDealing` and a sequence of `nextCard` calls.

Finally your Game class can concentrate on the mechanics of laying out and manipulating the cards.  I am assuming that the number of columns is fixed, but that the number of rows may vary, so I implemented the board as an array of `Lists`, where each column is a `List`.

```
public class Game {
    final int numColumns = 7;
    ArrayList<Card>[] board = new ArrayList[numColumns];

    Game() {
       for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
           board[column] = new ArrayList<Card>();
        }
        Pack pack = new Pack();
        pack.shuffle();
        pack.startDealing();
        int numRows = 7;
        // loop over rows.In this stage i want to transfer all the codes in an array.
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; row++) {
            // Add #columns - row# cards to this row
            for (int column=row; column<numColumns; column++) {
                Card card = pack.nextCard();
                if(column == row) card.show();
                board[column].add(row, card);
            }
        }
    }
    public int numRows() {
        int numRows = 0;
        for (List column : board) {
            numRows = Math.max(numRows, column.size());
        }
        return numRows;
    }
    public int columnSize(int column) {
        return board[column].size();
    }
    public void printBoard () {
       for(int row = 0; row < numRows(); row++) {
           for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
               if(board[column].size() > row) {
                   Card card = board[column].get(row);
                   System.out.print(card);
               }
               System.out.print("\t");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game g = new Game();
        g.printBoard();
    }
}
```

The remaining cards, which I assume are your bank, are still in the `pack` and you can deal them with `pack.nextCard()`.  You can add these dealt cards to a new `List` so that you can keep track of them.  To go through the cards again, create a new `Pack` from the `List` and `startDealing()` again.

Comment: You Understand my question. Yup, but how can i apply that codes in my codes ?

Comment: I have greatly expanded my answer.

Comment: It is okay if i put all that in one class ?

Comment: You could if you chose to.  Personally I wouldn't as you could then reuse the `Card` and `Pack` classes in different games.

Comment: Oh Okay. Last question, how I to put the lower part remaining string in new array bank. Like in the solitaire only 1 string is show by each column. The remaining  string will put in the array bank.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Do you want to put all the hidden cards in a column in a new `List`?  Something like `       public List<Card> bank(int column) {
           List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();
           for(int row = 0; row < columnSize(column) - 1; row++) {
               Card card = board[column].get(row);
               if(!card.isExposed()) {
                   list.add(card);
               }
           }
           return list;
        }
`

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it has answered your question.

Comment: Even not List. I can easily understand if it is in Array. In the solitaire there are only 1 cards facing in each column, all the remaining cards that are facing will got to an array. To serves as a bank in solitaire. And I notice that there are 52 strings but after i run the codes it is only 49 strings.

Comment: Again I am guessing what you are asking.  I have updated the answer to change how the cards are dealt and talked about how to handle the remaining cards.  You should try to modify the code yourself from now on.